# Aptana 3 didn't assist me to check browser compatibility in its Code Assist pop up

Tags: html, ide, aptana, aptana3

When I was typing codes in Aptana 3's editor, Code Assist pop up must show the browser compatibility check like this.

http://aptana.com/images/product/S3-1-sm.png

(I can't upload pic. Cos I'm just new to Stack Overflow. Sorry for your inconvenience!!!)

But in my case it didn't show any browser icons and just said element names and HTML Core. That's it. I want to check that browser compatibility and wanna see these browser icons as well. So what should i do??????

Answer (score 1):

You should choose "Web" as primary project nature in your project settings.

Answer (score 0):

You need to configure your Aptana installation.

Go on Windows menu -> Preferences
Aptana Studio -> Content Assist

And then check the browser you need have informations for.

Printscreen on -> http://www.image-heberg.fr/files/132813181897055.png

Regards